# How do I prove that $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(-a,b)$

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

How do I prove that $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(-a,b)$?

---

Here is what I have tried:
Let $d=\gcd(a,b)$ and $d'=\gcd(-a,b)$

Then $d|a$, $d|b$, $d'|(-a)$, $d'|b$ $\implies d'|(b-a)$ and $d|(a+b)$. Then there is some $k,t\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $b-a=kd'$ and $a+b=td$, but am now unsure what to do, and am not sure whether or not I am overcomplicating potentially trivial proof.

Comment: Please [search for answers](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cgcd(a%2Cb)%3D%5Cgcd(-a%2Cb)%24%2C%20AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com&p=1) before posting questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$d' | -a  \implies d'| a\;$ and $\;d'|b$ . Therefore, $d'|d$.

similarly, $d|a \implies d|-a\;$ and $\; d|b\;$ therefore, $d|d'$

$\implies d=d'$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).